# CCTray Authorisation Issues

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, continuous-integration, cctray

I'm having some authentication issues with CCTray (version 1.6.7981). If I specify an Authorisation Mode of "WinLogin authentication" no projects are listed & my AD account is locked out shortly thereafter.

If I specify "User name/password authentication" then the "Available Projects" list is populated as expected, and I can then select from this list and monitor the builds.

However, there are a couple of issues with the latter authorisation. Firstly, if my pc is rebooted then the following message is displayed against each project:

Error: Project '{project}' not found on server

Secondly (and more importantly), the password specified (which is my AD password) is displayed in cleartext within cctray-settings.xml (default location is C:\Documents and Settings{username}\Application Data.

Ideally I'd like to get the "WinLogin authentication" working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you happen to solve this problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: 'fraid not. Gave up on using CCTray in the interim.

Comment: I have the same problem.

AFAIK there is also an opened issue, but it seems no one cares to solve it...
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/issues/205

Answer (score 1):

To go about this you will need to create a Service Account in Active Directory. In window service(services.msc) look for the CruiseControl.net service and configure it to Log on As. This will prevent clear text login information being passed around.